# Assign rows based on number of "chances" a user has

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to assign jobs to users based on a score (number of "chances") calculated from previous jobs they have done. Here's my table of users:

```
user    chances
Anna    6
Barry   4
Steve   3
Jackson 3
Helga   3
Maureen 3
Paul    3
Karen   2
Anita   2
Samson  2
Frank   2
Jean    1
Lilly   1
Boris   1
```

In another table, I have 100 rows of unassigned `jobs` (with currently NULL `user`), e.g.

```
id  title               user
1   Sort filing         NULL
2   Clean office        NULL
3   Order stationery    NULL
```

I want to assign these jobs to the users above using a weighting based on the number of "chances" they have. For example, Anna will have 6 chances to be assigned one of these `jobs`, while Boris will have 1.

I've been playing around with a CASE which will assign a `user` to `jobs`, but nothing is satisfactory.

What's the best way for me to achieve this? Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand the plan here. What's the "chance" weighted against? Would Anna have a 6% probability of getting a job, or a 60% probability? (compared to Boris, at 1% or 10%) Can you say more about the context?

Comment: @Stidgeon Looks like it's just weighting against the other users. So `Anna` has twice the chance of being chosen as `Steve`. They can be converted to probabilities by dividing by the total of all chances, as in Strawberry's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you're after something like this...

```
SELECT user 
FROM my_table 
ORDER BY RAND() * chances * (SELECT SUM(chances) FROM my_table) DESC ;
```

Comment: That's only half the battle, how do you then assign each of them to a different row in the `jobs` table?

Comment: Is there really a need to multiply by the sum? That's the same for everyone, so the order is the same without it.

Comment: Yep, something like that

Comment: Thanks @strawberry, that's pretty much exactly what I'm after - thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the `changes` are a small number and integers, then the easiest way might be:

```
update anothertable at
    set user = (select user
                from chances c cross join
                     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all
                      select 4 union all select 5 union all select 6
                     ) n
                     on c.chances <= n.n
                 where at.user is null
                 order by rand()
                 limit 1
                );
```

The `where` clause is just so MySQL doesn't get the (brilliant) idea of optimizing away the subquery and only calling it once.

Comment: Thanks, but `order by rand()` just seems to produce a random response, i.e. I ran it 100 times and there doesn't seem to be any weighting of e.g. Anna above Boris.

Comment: @huey . . . That doesn't make sense.  The `join` in the `from` clause should be providing the weights.